# What does get do in c#?

Tags: c#, forms, get

I took this code from elsewhere in order to show and hide forms effectively. Whilst I understand most of it, I don't understand what get does in this context and in general. can this be explained?
WinForms

```
public class FormProvider
{
    public static Form1 frm1
    {
        get
        {
            if (_frm1 == null)
            {
                _frm1 = new Form1();
            }
            return _frm1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know where the documentation is? Did you read that first and not find anything that helped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's nothing else other than syntax wrapper over automatically generated function

```
public static Form1 get_frm1()
{       
   return _frm1;       
}
```

So every time you reference `FormProvider.frm1`, it's like you are calling `FormProvider.get_frm1()`

In fact if you try to code something like this:

```
public class A {

    public string Name {get;}

    public string get_Name() {
       return "James Bond";
    }
}
```

it will give compile-time error, as there is a collision of definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Those are called [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) in C#

Properties are a way to encapsulate fields in such a way that they can be accessed with these so called "Getter" and "Setter" methods, that could contain any logic needed.

In this case, the "Getter" will return an existing instance of your `Form1` (if there is one) or create a new instance if none is found, assign it to the `_form1` field and return that.

I suggest you research on the link above for further understanding.

Answer (score 0):

**its is used as getter method for the property**

### From MSDN

---

> Properties combine aspects of both fields and methods. To the user of
> an object, a property appears to be a field, accessing the property
> requires the same syntax. To the implementer of a class, a property is
> one or two code blocks, representing a get accessor and/or a set
> accessor. The code block for the get accessor is executed when the
> property is read; the code block for the set accessor is executed when
> the property is assigned a new value. A property without a set
> accessor is considered read-only. A property without a get accessor is
> considered write-only. A property that has both accessors is
> read-write.
>
> Unlike fields, properties are not classified as variables. Therefore,
> you cannot pass a property as a ref (C# Reference) or out (C#
> Reference) parameter.

#### The set Accessor

> The set accessor resembles a method whose return type is void. It uses
> an implicit parameter called value, whose type is the type of the
> property. In the following example, a set accessor is added to the
> Value property:

```
**When you assign a value to the property, the set accessor is invoked by using an argument that provides the new value**
```

consider this class for example

```
class DemoClass
{
    private int value;
    public Int32 Value
    {
        get 
        { 
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

if look at the compiled assembly in the reflector u will notice like

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit DemoClass
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: ldarg.0 
        L_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        L_0006: ret 
    }


    .property instance int32 Value
    {
        .get instance int32 ConsoleApplication1.DemoClass::get_Value()
        .set instance void ConsoleApplication1.DemoClass::set_Value(int32)
    }


    .field private int32 value

}
```

Comment: ...isn't it a getter method rather?

Comment: How is `get` a property **setter**? And even if that's the case, you need to provide much more information if you want this to be an answer. As it is, it's a comment to the original question at best.

Comment: @KenWhite - my bad, typo issue!

Comment: You still need to add more content if you want this to be an answer.

Comment: Sure. :-) I was just looking for another couple of sentences that explained your answer, though. :-)

Comment: If you're citing something (MSDN here), be sure to link to it.

Answer (score 0):

`frm1` is a property.

Properties generally have a getter `get` and an optional setter `set`.

These are used to provide special implementation when accessing your `Property`

In this case, if the property's backer `_frm1` (which is a field) is `null`, the getter is responsible for setting it to a new instance of `Form1`.